# Media queries breakpoint in safari

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1279px) {
    ...
}
```

In Safari on 1280px site looking like for 1279px, but not in Chrome.
In Chrome @media start work on 1279px.

How to make work @media in Safari like in Chrome?

Comment: Is this on a retina screen where you can count half pixels? That is, can you resize the window to 1279.5 pixels?